# Using scipy.stats.bernoulli to simulate 1/3 probability

Tags: python, distribution, scipy.stats, uniform-distribution, bernoulli-probability

Our task is to recreate the famous fair coin flip (p=0.5) using only `bernoulli.rvs()` to generate function with uniform discrete distribution (outcomes = 0,1,2). Is it possible to do using only bernoulli function form `scipy.stats`?

Comment: why are there 3 outcomes? A coin toss or Bernoulli trial should have 2 outcomes, right?

Comment: Yes, there are two outcomes in a single flip, but, for instance, two flips generate 4 outcomes (heads - H and tails -T ) -HH, HT, TH, TT with equal probability 0.25. We can take three favourable and retoss the resst until we get the fovourable one (HH – start over HT 0.33 TH 0.33 TT 0.33)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible using acceptance/rejection (as you described in a comment).  I'm not sure why you asked this since you seem to know how to do it, but since nobody has posted an implementation yet here you go:

```python
from scipy.stats import bernoulli
import numpy as np

MATCHSET = np.array([[0,0], [0,1], [1,0]])

def gen_uniform_3():
    while True:
        ary = bernoulli.rvs(1/2, size = 2)
        for i in range(3):
            if np.array_equal(ary, MATCHSET[i]):
                return i
```

The `while True` will keep trying as long as the generated pair is `[1,1]`, but will return a value of 0, 1, or 2 for the other three equally likely outcomes.